# How to split array into n chunks given their sizes in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, split, dynamic-arrays

Say I have an array of 10000 integers, it is to be split into 3 sub-arrays ("num_jobs" in this case). In my code I have found the length for each subarray, and lengths are stored in an array "parts" in the function "split()".

**My code:**

```
// Function that prints  
// the required sequence 
int * split(int x, int n) //x=10000,n=3
{ 
  
    // If we cannot split the  
    // number into exactly 'N' parts 
    int *parts;
    parts = new int[n];
    if(x < n) 
    {
        return parts; 
    }
          
  
    // If x % n == 0 then the minimum  
    // difference is 0 and all  
    // numbers are x / n 
    else if (x % n == 0) 
    { 
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        { 
        parts[i] = (x/n); 
        }
    } 
    else
    { 
  
        // upto n-(x % n) the values  
        // will be x / n  
        // after that the values  
        // will be x / n + 1 
        int zp = n - (x % n); 
        int pp = x/n; 
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)  
        { 
  
            if(i>= zp) 
            parts[i] = (pp + 1); 
            else
            parts[i] = pp; 
        } 
    }
    // cout<<parts[0]<<parts[1]<<parts[2];
    return parts;
} 
      

main()
{
    int num_jobs;
    cout << "Enter Number of Jobs: "; // Type a number and press enter
    cin >> num_jobs; // Get user input from the keyboard  
    int sizeOfInputArray = 10000;
    int* partsArray = split(sizeOfInputArray, num_jobs);
    
    for(int index=0;index<num_jobs;index++)
    {
        cout<<partsArray[index];
        }
}
```

What I am trying to do is create num_jobs number of arrays, each of the length present in "partsArray". For 10000 length, and given 3 num_jobs, it returns an array containing 3333, 3333, 3334, which represents the size of each subarray. How can I handle the split of a large array with 10000 length?

Comment: (1) Are you required to use c-arrays?  In C++ you should be using `std::vector`.  (2) How do you want to distribute the "left-over" elements if `n` does not exactly divide the initial size?

Comment: 1. Create `n` containers. 2. Iterate over your array and put element `i` into container `i*n/10000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, try to avoid using raw arrays if you can. `std::vector` is pretty much the same in terms of performance and internal implementation but at the same time provides robust interface and handles memory for you.

As for C-style arrays, you can't split a single array into parts. Let's say you have

```
int* arr = new int[n];
```

you can't then *reinterpret* that array and start treating it like 2 separate arrays, because once you decide to free its memory you will release `arr` as a whole, and you can't change that behaviour. You can however work with just parts of your array. Let's say call a function that will take an array as an argument together with starting and ending index, something like

```
void doMagic(int* arr, int begin, int end) {
    for (int i = begin; i < end; ++i) {
        //do something with arr[i]
    }
}
```

Note that you can do the same with `std::vector`. If you want to extract data from your array and prepare individual smaller arrays containing parts of your original array you will have to do it manually. Again using trick with `begin` and `end` indexes and copying values in a loop from original array to new array. You can achieve the same thing with `std::vector` as one of it's constructors can take two `iterators` and copy a range of elements.

Lastly, to avoid problems with calculating size of sub-array, when total size is not easily divisible by number of chunks (like your 10,000 divided by 3) you can instead calculate let's call them division points or ranges. If your array has **n** elements and you want to split it into **x** parts, you can calculate `begin` and `end` index for **current** chunk as follow.

```
int begin = (n * current) / x;
int end = ((n * (current + 1)) / x) - 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, it would be simpler to work with std::vector, but I give you an example with C arrays anyway :

```
int ** splitArray(int *inputArray, int *parts, int num_jobs) {
    int ** subarrays = new int*[3];
    int * ptr = inputArray;
    for (int i=0; i< num_jobs; i++) {
        subarrays[i] = new int[parts[i]];
        memcpy(subarrays[i], ptr, parts[i]);
        ptr += parts[i];
    }
    return subarrays;
}

int main()
{
    int sizeOfInputArray = 10000;
    int * inputArray = new int[sizeOfInputArray];
    memset(inputArray, 0xff, sizeOfInputArray * sizeof(int)); //This sets all index to -1
    int num_jobs = 3;
    int* partsArray = split(sizeOfInputArray, num_jobs);
    
    int ** subarrays = splitArray(inputArray, partsArray, num_jobs);
    std::cout << "\n" << subarrays[0][0] << " "; //==> -1
    std::cout << "\n" << subarrays[1][0] << " "; //==> -1
    std::cout << "\n" << subarrays[2][0] << " "; //==> -1
    
    //Releases allocated memory
    for(int i=0;i<num_jobs;i++) delete subarrays[i];
    delete subarrays;
    delete inputArray;
    delete partsArray;
    return 0;
}
```